# Should templated classes be precisely as fast as untemplated classes?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, templates

I have a non-general-purpose object that only exists to be in collections.  A library I'm writing that defines the object, let's call it `Collected`, and two implementations of the collection, that should have advantages in different scenarios.  Let's call them `Collection1` and `Collection2`.  The collection is central to high-speed processing in this application so let's say performance is paramount.

The code for `Collected` is identical between the two, except 1) the ctor param that takes its collection, and 2) the member variable storing it.

So, I'm tempted to replace `Collected`  with `TemplatedCollected<class T>` with the obvious code change.
Apps using the library could decide centrally which they want, and either define `MyCollected` as `TemplatedCollected<Collection1>` or `TemplatedCollected<Collection2>`.

However if there is **any chance it is any faster**, I could make a `Collected1` and `Collected2` class that are identical except which collection they support.  (Again, the app could define `MyCollected` to their needs.)

Comment: All things equal, yes, just as fast. In the case you describe, the template would essentially be just shorthand for the duplicated code, and there should be zero runtime overhead to it.

Comment: Would you please include some basic example code in your question?  Usually we don't template things for no reason...but you seem to have three cases: plain Collected, TemplatedCollected, and Collected1+Collected2.  If the first option (a single non-template class) is usable, why are you considering the other options?

Comment: While some generalisation can be made, best design is often specific for a particular class. Why are you using different colllections? Would it make sense to convert the collection? Would it make sense to have a base class and derived classes and use virtual functions? If the class has 3 lines, one might not use the same approach as if it have a few thousand lines for example. Also, if the collection has 5 items, one might take a different decision that if it has 500000 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templated classes only overhead is because they generate a new class.  This takes *compile time*, and *compile memory*, and can result in *more program code* being generated.  Finally, the symbol length of templates can sometimes be longer than you'd write by hand.

The last, however, is only because having a template generate program code is easier than hand-writing it.  If you where to copy-paste a template implementation twice over the template would be no worse.

The largest cost is the fact that splitting template implementation from the header is a bit of a headache.

However, you are dealing with performance.  If performance matters, you should be profiling.  You shouldn't rule out using a template -- the ability to put optimizations in one place and have it apply to both is high value.